# How can I tell when an SVG is finished rendering

Tags: svg

I have an SVG which takes a short time to load (about 2-3) seconds. During that time, it looks a little funny. Is there anyway to tell when an SVG is done rendering so I can put up a spinner or hide it or something else?

Comment: What platform? Web, Windows, iOS?

Comment: Everything. This is for an application which is both on the web and and on the iPad (as a native app).

Comment: please provide relevant information, e.g. code snippets, screenshots. by the way, 2-3 seconds is not a short time for rendering.

Comment: 2-3 seconds is not a short time for rendering? Thank you, I didn't realize that.
I tried rendering a SVG. Not much more. The SVG was created from a PDF  using http://www.pdftron.com/pdf2svg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't tell. The restriction is to safeguard user's security. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608030 for a more detailed explanation of when this was considered for Firefox but other UAs will come to the same conclusion so you're unlikely to be able to do this in any UA ever.

From the referenced bug...

> Doing anything conditionally on the visitedness of a link seems dangerous. I haven't tried this, but suppose the attacker wants to know if the user has been to example.com. An attacker could set the href of a hyperlink to example.com, then navigate to example.com in a hidden iframe. If a MozAfterPaint event fires on the document where the hyperlink lives, you'd know the user hasn't been to www.example.com yet. Otherwise, they have.

Comment: **1.** please add references to back you claims. **2.** the linked bug refers to the documentation, not the functionality.

Comment: @EliranMalka Note that Robert is a contributor to Firefox, particularly for SVG. You should generally trust what he writes. :)

Comment: i respect that, the answer should be broaden regardless, for the benefit of others.

Comment: In Firefox we had that functionality, security researches demonstrated timing issues which compromised user security and the linked bug is the one that contains the patch that disabled the functionality and also tells you why.

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but the reasoning seems off. What security hole would an `onrendered` event present? The asker isn't looking for anything regarding history. He wants to detect that the svg is done.

Comment: @N-ate the user isn't looking for that but other people would exploit it as already explained in the answer.

Comment: The same could be done with any js, html, css, img, etc. Timing the load time will give a feel for whether it came from cache or was retrieved remotely. Why do svg need to be more secure than every other resource loaded in a browser?

Comment: @N-ate Evil entity creates a page and puts links on it, maybe they do the links in the same colour as the background. Then they get people to visit the page and time the rendering for differences between visited and unvisited, remember the browser needs to do more work to colour visited links. They can tell who visited what other page. Knowing their page loading times won't help them.

Comment: Adding reference to a script of another site on a fully loaded page will certainly tell you if they've been to that page. If the user has visited the page the cached script will load almost instantly. If they have not visited the site it will load slowly.

Comment: The same is true for any other cache-able resource.

Comment: @N-ate Sure, which is precisely why we do not provide websites with the ability to time such things.

Comment: 1. Wait for all assets to load. 2. Note the time. 3. Write a script tag that references a script on otherdomain.com 4. Poll the global javascript space for known jso. 5. Note the time when the foreign jso appears. 6. Calculate the differences in time.

Comment: Besides an event could easily be provided for svgs by differentiating between constructed svg (drawn in the browser) and image files that are svg.