# How to know when an SVG finished rendering?

Tags: html, svg, html-rendering

I'm trying to export a bunch of html pages that includes svg graphs to an image.
I use React to render everything and html2canvas to convert the page, but the problem is that the graphs are rarely rendered. When I add a timeout after the render, it works fine. But I'm rendering lots of pages on after another. A fixed timeout may introduce unneccessary delays or (worse) prevent rendering of very complex svgs.

I reckon this is due to the fact that the svgs DOM is loaded but overall has not finished rendering. Is there a way to detect when an svg or say a full html page has finished rendering completely? Since I'm using electron I'm ok with solutions that apply only to chrome, if available.

I have seen [How can I tell when an SVG is finished rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648693/how-can-i-tell-when-an-svg-is-finished-rendering) but it's 9 years old and seems to be firefox specific.

Comment: It's not Firefox specific, the security/privacy reasoning applies equally to all browsers.

Comment: So my best bet is to use the timer?

Comment: your best bet is to ask a question with a [mcve] so we can all understand what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Won't the `onload` Event trigger

```html
<img src="http://placeholder.pics/svg/100" 
     onload="document.body.append(`Loaded: ${this.src}`)">
```

Comment: that's when it's loaded into the DOM, not when it's finished rendering. There is no rendering complete signal for the reasons given in the linked Q&A.

Comment: Ah, and I see OP is using React.. I'm staying away from this one